# Do black holes have a puff pastry point?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, acceleration

If a person falls into a certain sized black hole they accelerate very fast, which increases the g forces on them.
These g forces flatten the person out into a pancake.
As the person falls further into the BH the acceleration is less even and they turn into spaghetti.

Is there a puff pastry point between pancakes and spaghetti where the person becomes their normal shape again?

Comment: I think you're confusing free fall and standing above high gravity on a surface.   Free fall into a dense object, you always stretch.  Standing on a surface feeling gravity you squash.   There's no middle point between the two cause the two happen for different reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do black holes have a puff pastry point?

No.

> If a person falls into a certain sized black hole they accelerate very fast, which increases the g forces on them.

They don't feel any g forces at all, because there aren't any.

> These g forces flatten the person out into a pancake.

There aren't any, a falling person doesn't flatten into a pancake. That only happens when they hit the ground.

> As the person falls further into the BH the acceleration is less even and they turn into spaghetti.

Spaghettification occurs because the force of gravity is greater closer to the gravitating body. If you were falling feet-first, the force of gravity at your feet is greater than the force of gravity where your head is.

> Is there a puff pastry point between pancakes and spaghetti where the person becomes their normal shape again?

No.

Comment: What if the person was inside a steel box? Would there be a puff pastry point?

Comment: No.   If the box was suspended above the black hole the person would feel the G's and be squashed.   If the box was orbiting the black hole the person would feel weightless and no stretching or squashing, though there could be some relativistic effects.    If the box was falling into the black hole from a height the person would be stretched and in time, turned into spaghetti.